# When using an R kernel, is it possible to get Variable Explorer / Data Viewer functionality in Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions

When running Python Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code, there's a wonderful, useful variable [explorer and data viewer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_variable-explorer-and-data-viewer). Is this possible with R notebooks in addition to Python ones?

I haven't been able to find a way to get equivalent functionality with an R kernel, although I know that [it is available](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r#_workspace-viewer) for a regular R terminal through the R extension.