# Variables Not Displaying in Jupyter Notebook Using IRkernel on Visual Studio Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've encountered a persistent issue while working with Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio Code, specifically when using the R language through IRkernel. After executing code cells that define variables, these variables do not appear in the Variables pane. This behavior is inconsistent with what I experience when using a Python kernel, where variables are displayed as expected.

Here's a step-by-step description of the issue:

I create a new Jupyter Notebook in VS Code and select the IRkernel for R.
I write and execute a simple R code that defines a variable, for example, x <- 5.
Although the code executes without error and the output displays correctly in the notebook cell, the defined variable x does not show up in the Variables pane. It indicates "No variables defined" despite the successful execution of the code.
This is the behavior I observe with the R kernel, whereas switching to a Python kernel within the same environment allows variables to display normally after execution. I've ensured that my IRkernel is properly installed and up-to-date.

Here are the versions I'm using:

R version: R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
IRkernel version: 1.3.2
Visual Studio Code version: 1.86.1
Jupyter extension for VS Code version: 0.1.5
I've attached a screenshot demonstrating the issue with the R kernel.
[With R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gupfE.png)
I've attached a screenshot demonstrating the issue with the Python kernel.
[With Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA8tq.png)

I've attempted the following troubleshooting steps with no success:

Restarting VS Code.
Reinstalling both the Jupyter extension and the IRkernel.
Checking the VS Code settings for any misconfigurations related to R.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this issue. Has anyone else encountered this problem, or does anyone know of a solution or a workaround?

Thank you in advance for your help!

After noticing that variables were not being displayed in the Jupyter Notebook's variable explorer pane when using the IRkernel, I began troubleshooting the issue with the expectation that any variables defined in executed code cells would be listed in the variable explorer, similar to how they are when using a Python kernel.

Here's what I tried:

Re-executing the Code Cells: I first suspected a glitch and simply tried re-executing the code cells that defined variables.

Expected: The variable explorer to update and show the defined variables.

Result: The variable explorer remained empty, stating "No variables defined".

Restarting the Kernel and Clearing Outputs: I restarted the R kernel and cleared all outputs to start fresh, thinking that previous errors might have caused a problem with the variable tracking.

Expected: A clean state that might resolve any hidden issues and display variables upon re-execution of code.

Result: Still, no variables appeared in the variable explorer after code execution.

Reinstalling IRkernel: I reinstalled the IRkernel package within R to ensure that there were no issues with the installation itself.

Expected: A fresh install of IRkernel to fix any potential corruption or misconfiguration issues.

Result: The installation was successful, but the problem persisted with no change in behavior.

Checking Visual Studio Code Settings: I reviewed the settings in Visual Studio Code related to R and Jupyter to make sure nothing was misconfigured.

Expected: To find and correct a setting that might have been causing the issue.

Result: All settings appeared to be correct, and adjusting related configurations did not resolve the issue.

Searching for Similar Issues: I searched online for similar issues, thinking that it might be a known problem with a documented solution.

Expected: To find forum posts, documentation, or issue tracker entries that addressed the same issue.

Result: While I found discussions around variable explorer features, nothing matched the specific problem I was experiencing.

Throughout this process, I was expecting to find a clear cause or at least a workaround for the issue, but the actual result was that the problem remained unresolved, with no variables being displayed in the variable explorer of the Jupyter Notebook using the IRkernel, despite successful execution of code defining variables.

Comment: This was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76410283/8508004), sadly there is no answer but usually that doesn't mean you should open your own new, competing question. [Here](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-use-jupyter-r-kernel-with-visual-studio-code/) says "You can use the debugger to step through your code, set breakpoints, and inspect variables"; I wonder if then maybe you are looking in the wrong place? I know from general use and things such as [this issue at the IRkernel repo 'Support debugger protocol'](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/686) that in ...

Comment: <continued> the R kernel doesn't offer as many features as Python ipykernel. Even the ipykernel was slow to allow some features like debugging, see [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/enabling-the-jupyterlab-debugger-with-ipykernel-8d7248f522b0) where in 2021 it first says, "Unfortunately, the reference Python kernel, ipykernel, did not support debugging yet, until now!" So your expectation may just be wrong at this time. Use of R directly in VSCode or in RStudio is the workaround.

Comment: "Oh, I hadn't noticed that there was already a question about that. Thank you for answering it so quickly